# Attempted to read or write protected memory. PKCS11Interop

Tags: pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I am getting Access violation exception in the highlighed line.

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I have the certificate on the `hsm` and the `label` . I am building my application as x64

```
public void getCertificateFromHSM(string certLabel) {

    List<ObjectAttribute> objectAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
    objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE));
    objectAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_LABEL, certLabel));

    **session.FindObjectsInit(objectAttributes);** --Exception from here

    // Get search results
    List<ObjectHandle> foundObjects = session.FindObjects(2);

    // Terminate searching
    session.FindObjectsFinal();


    // Prepare list of empty attributes we want to read
    List<CKA> attributes = new List<CKA>();
    attributes.Add(CKA.CKA_LABEL);
    attributes.Add(CKA.CKA_VALUE);
}
```

I am getting exception from this line `session.FindObjectsInit();`. I am new to `pkcs11`.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

I also tried to build the application as 32 bit by passing the 32bit `crypto.dll` ,but in that case i am getting exception from this line in `PKCS11Interop Net.Pkcs11Interop.LowLevelAPI81.Delegates.InitializeWithGetF‌​unctionList(IntPtr libraryHandle)` and the exception is

> Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32. OverflowExcepiton was unhandled.

Comment: I am getting exception from this line  (session.FindObjectsInit(); ) . I am new to pkcs11 . Any help in this regard is appreciated.  I also tried to build the application as 32 bit by passing the 32bit crypto dll ,but in that case i am getting exception from this line in PKCS11Interop Net.Pkcs11Interop.LowLevelAPI81.Delegates.InitializeWithGetFunctionList(IntPtr libraryHandle)   and the exception is {"Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32."}  OverflowExcepiton was unhandled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using wrong set of HighLevelAPIs. You need to use classes from `Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI` namespace without any numbers at the end.

In other words you need to use following line

```
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI;
```

in your code instead of

```
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI81;
```

See [Pkcs11Interop library architecture](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/doc/ARCHITECTURE.md) for more info and you can also take a look at [official code samples](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/3.3.0/doc/CODE_SAMPLES.md) which are using `Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI` too.

Comment: Great help .Thank you jariq :)

Comment: @SandeepSrinivasIndraganti please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem. You will get a badge and other stackoverflow goodies :)